# Trello Filters used with a Power Up

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

I'm currently working on a PowerUp that will display Trello Cards in additional Quarterly and Annual calendar views.  I've tried replicating the setup of the Calendar Power Up, but as far as I can tell, it's developed internally and not stuck with the rules the rest of the Power Ups are tied to.   One big item that I can't seem to figure out is how to filter the cards within my Power Up based on the cards filtered in the main Trello board.   Does anyone have of know of an example showing how this can be done?   Is this simply not possible?   Any help or general direction pointing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-pluginData)? The property is read only so I guess you only need an app key.